# python import error in gzip.py ; where is zlib

Tags: python, python-import

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 that has python 2.7 as its default. I have installed python 3.3 in /opt/python3.3 (using ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3) and have created a symlink /usr/bin/python33 that points to the executable in /opt. There is already a symlink /usr/bin/python3 that points to the python 3.2 (actually it points to python3.2mu: if you can explain as a side note as to why this 'mu' is included :) ) installation that came with the ubuntu installation.
I installed distribute tools using python3 without any problems. But when I tried the same thing with python33 it gave me the following error:

```
ankur@junk-mechanism:~$ sudo python33 distribute_setup.py
Extracting in /tmp/tmp685lyf
lzma module is not available
not a bzip2 file
gzip module is not available
bad checksum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 550, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 547, in main
    return _install(tarball, _build_install_args(options))
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 78, in _install
    tar = tarfile.open(tarball)
  File "/opt/python3.3/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py", line 1578, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully" + str(name) + repr(fileobj))
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully/home/ankur/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gzNone
```

So in tarfile.py, the classmethod Tarfile.open calls the class method Tarfile.gzopen where the module gzip is imported:

```
    try:
        import gzip
        gzip.GzipFile
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        raise CompressionError("gzip module is not available")
```

The error raised here is ImportError because gzip.py has an import zlib which it cant find. But even the other installations of python (2.7 and 3.2) dont contain zlib in the respective standard lib /usr/lib/pythonx.x/lib/. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't build everything because of missing dependencies.  You can try getting the missing dependencies and rebuilding.  To get the missing dependencies, I'd just work from what Python 3.2 requires and do:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3
```

Then you can reconfigure and rebuild Python 3.3 to get all the required modules.

Another option is to use the dead snakes ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

I usually install the -dev package too so that I can install packages that have C extension modules:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am referring to your first suggestion. how will building dependencies for 3.2 help me in reconfiguring 3.3. I am new to this. Any pointers would help. Thanks

Comment: also if you have two different installations, a 3.3 and a 3.3-dev, how do you make sure that the packages that have C extension modules are available to the 3.3 after installation?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long... had to work. :-)  You had said that you built Python 3.3.  `apt-get build-dep python3` will make sure your system has all the necessary dependencies installed so that when you run `./configure` and `make`, all the bits will be found and the full suite of extensions will be built.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.3` installs the base python package.  Unfortunately, development headers and some other bits are left out.  To get those, you have to install `python3.3-dev`.  Anything that would like to build a C extension module will need the development headers to build.  So it's not two different installations I'm talking about.  It's the base package plus the development bits.  I'm not sure I understand your last question.  Maybe you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: thanks. I was under the impression that 3.3 and 3.3-dev would be two different installations. But your explanation has been helpful. I have successfully installed distribute_tools as well. But I am curious as to where and how these headers are being installed and made available. The include folder in the python dir structure has the same number of files as there were before the installation of the dev package. I guess my question is more intrinsic to the behavior of linux than python itself. Or am I fiddling on the  wrong roof?

Comment: A couple of things.  Are you looking at the Python 3.3 that you installed, or the one installed by the packages?  I suspect the former.  To see what a package installed, you can use the `dpkg -L` command in Debian-based Linux distros.  So `dpkg -L python3.3` and `dpkg -L python3.3-dev` will show you what each one installs.  The python3.3 doesn't install any headers, and you'll see that the python3.3-dev package does.  And yes, this is more inherent to Linux, file system layouts, and a whole host of other things rather than Python itself.

Comment: I see. I am extremely curious and would look into this. Thanks again for all your help. As a side note, let me know what you would advise as a good starting point to get deeper.

Comment: You're welcome!  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good book to get you moving in the right direction on Linux.  I grew up with this stuff and picked it up as I went along.  If you're interested in packages, how they are made, maintained, etc., then the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) is a good place to start, but it's not really for beginners on Linux.  Sorry!

Comment: No problems. I will pave my way through as this is very interesting. :)